# Merging banking and classic style in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

Writing my CV  in the `moderncv` package, I was caught between the *classic* style for the main body, and *banking* style for the header/title. I'm not sure how to merge the two formats. Also on the Banking Style header I would like to add an additional item for LinkedIn.

When looking through other questions I saw recommendations to add an MWE, but I'm not sure how to do this either seeing as I'm fairly new to using LaTeX. I can add it if someone can point me in the right direction.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take from `moderncvstylebanking.sty` the parts in charge of formatting the title and use them in your `.tex` file with the `casual` style; to add your LinkedIn information you can use `\social[linkedin]{john.doe}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
% commands from moderncvstylebanking.sty to have the title
% from that style
\newcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}{%
    {~~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~~}}% the \rmfamily is required to force Latin Modern fonts when using sans serif, as OMS/lmss/m/n is not defined and gets substituted by OMS/cmsy/m/n
%   internal command to add an element to the footer
%   it collects the elements in a temporary box, and checks when to flush the box
\newsavebox{\maketitlebox}%
\newsavebox{\maketitletempbox}%
\newlength{\maketitlewidth}%
\newlength{\maketitleboxwidth}%
\newif\if@firstmaketitleelement\@firstmaketitleelementtrue%
%   adds an element to the maketitle, separated by maketitlesymbol
%   usage: \addtomaketitle[maketitlesymbol]{element}
\newcommand*{\addtomaketitle}[2][\maketitlesymbol]{%
  \if@firstmaketitleelement%
    \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{\usebox{\maketitlebox}#2}%
  \else%
    \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{\usebox{\maketitlebox}#1#2}\fi%
  \settowidth{\maketitleboxwidth}{\usebox{\maketitletempbox}}%
  \ifnum\maketitleboxwidth<\maketitlewidth%
    \savebox{\maketitlebox}{\usebox{\maketitletempbox}}%
    \@firstmaketitleelementfalse%
  \else%
    \flushmaketitle{}\\%
    \savebox{\maketitlebox}{#2}%
    \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{#2}%
    \settowidth{\maketitleboxwidth}{\usebox{\maketitlebox}}%
    \@firstmaketitleelementfalse\fi}
%   internal command to flush the maketitle
\newcommand*{\flushmaketitle}{%
  \strut\usebox{\maketitlebox}%
  \savebox{\maketitlebox}{}%
  \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{}%
  \setlength{\maketitleboxwidth}{0pt}}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \hfil%
  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{%
    \centering%
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title) 
    % detailed information
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmaketitle}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\Huge\bfseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\Huge\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\normalsize\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!85}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}

\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \maketitle%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle}

\makeatother
% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{The title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]